# case specific calculation based on status of a column

Tags: sql-server

This is my fee table. It gets me the fee details for current month. If I do `SELECT * from FeeTest`, it will generate fee for current month as it is using `GETDATE()`. By default, IsPaid is set to false.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FeeTest](
    [ClassId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HeaderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FeeAmount] [money] NOT NULL,
    [FeePeriod]  AS ((datename(month,getdate())+', ')+datename(year,getdate())),
    [DueDate]  AS (CONVERT([date],dateadd(month,(-1),dateadd(month,datediff(month,(0),getdate())+(1),(9))))),
    [FeeBillGeneratedOn]  AS (CONVERT([date],dateadd(month,(-1),dateadd(month,datediff(month,(0),getdate())+(1),(0))))),
    [IsPaid] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [UNIQ_feeHeadersTest] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassId] ASC,
    [HeaderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FeeTest]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ClassId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Classes] ([ClassId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FeeTest]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([HeaderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[FeeHeaders] ([HeaderId])
GO
```

This is how I am getting fee details for all individual students

```
select Students.StudentId, Students.StudentName, Students.RegistrationNumber, FeeTest.FeePeriod, SUM(FeeTest.FeeAmount) AS TotalFee, FeeTest.DueDate, FeeTest.IsPaid
 from Students inner join FeeTest on Students.ClassId = FeeTest.ClassId group by Students.StudentId, Students.StudentName, Students.RegistrationNumber, FeeTest.DueDate,
 FeeTest.IsPaid, FeeTest.FeePeriod
```

This is where I am keeping monthly record of all students irrespective whether IsPaid is 0 or 1.

```
CREATE TABLE FeePaymentStatus
(
    studentId int not null primary key,
    studentName nvarchar(255) not null,
    registrationNumber nvarchar(9) not null,
    FeePeriod nvarchar(62) not null,
    FeeAmount money not null,
    dueDate date not null,
    IsPaid bit not null,
    CONSTRAINT [UNIQ_FeePeriod] UNIQUE CLUSTERED
    (
        [StudentId],
        [FeePeriod]
    )
);

INSERT INTO FeePaymentStatus
 select Students.StudentId, Students.StudentName, Students.RegistrationNumber, FeeTest.FeePeriod, SUM(FeeTest.FeeAmount) AS TotalFee, FeeTest.DueDate, FeeTest.IsPaid
 from Students inner join FeeTest on Students.ClassId = FeeTest.ClassId group by Students.StudentId, Students.StudentName, Students.RegistrationNumber, FeeTest.DueDate,
 FeeTest.FeePeriod, FeeTest.IsPaid
```

What I want to do next is add the fees for students who still have their IsPaid to 0 when I run this again in December.

```
select Students.StudentId, Students.StudentName, Students.RegistrationNumber, FeeTest.FeePeriod, SUM(FeeTest.FeeAmount) AS TotalFee, FeeTest.DueDate, FeeTest.IsPaid
 from Students inner join FeeTest on Students.ClassId = FeeTest.ClassId group by Students.StudentId, Students.StudentName, Students.RegistrationNumber, FeeTest.DueDate,
 FeeTest.IsPaid, FeeTest.FeePeriod
```

How do I achieve this? HeaderId in first piece of code does have a header which reads previous charges which has a default of 0. I am using SQL server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" =   
  CASE   
     WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'  
     WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'  
     WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'  
     WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'  
     ELSE 'Over $1000'  
  END  
FROM Production.Product
```